# Utilizar Navigation Drawer and Page Sliding Tab Strip

Tags: android-studio, github, importação, android-eclipse

Tentei de todas as formas que imagino importar esta biblioteca ([Navigation Drawer and Page Sliding Tab Strip](https://github.com/Balaji-K13/Navigation-drawer-page-sliding-tab-strip) ) em um projeto, porém, sem êxito. Segui o passo a passo (importando as outras bibliotecas que são obrigatórias pra essa biblioteca, importando como eu acho que seria) que diz em seu reade-me, porém, não funciona. Nem compila.

Como eu poderia fazer essa importação (em um projeto do zero mesmo, depois eu me viro) tanto no **Android Studio** quanto no **Eclipse**?

Comment: No eclipse utilizando o SDK isso já vem importado se não me falhe a memória.

Comment: link do eclipse com SDK se lhe interessar
http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: 1. Extrair todas a bibliotecas em pastas separadas.
 2. Importar biblioteca por biblioteca como projeto (aplicação android já existente) p o Eclipse.
 3. Em cada projeto, adicionar o jar android.v4.
 4. Clique com o direito em cima do projeto principal, propriedades, ANDROID, em library, e adiciona os projetos **actionbarsherlock** e **PagerSlidingTabStrip**, aplica e ok.
 5. Vai na aba PROJECTS (no eclipse) e seleciona "clean", "clean all projects" e pronto.

Só não funcionou o arquivo PageSlidingTabStripFragment. Dá erro na linha 43, "getChildFragmentManager()" não está definido. Dicas?